# Command window doesn't open for console application

Tags: c#

I have written a very basic introductory C# program as below,when I build the application there are no errors in the output however I don't see the string "Welcome to .net" being printed?I looked at other answers related to it on added `Console.ReadKey();` but still I don't see the string being printed on console, as a matter of fact I dont see any command window being opened,what am I doing wrong?

```
using System; 
namespace welcome
{
    public class Mainclass
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to .net ");    
            Console.ReadKey();    
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT1:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you are building a console app and not a windows form app or some other type of project?

Comment: building isn't the same as running. If you built a car, would you expect it to automatically start and go forward?

Comment: You probably don't do anything wrong.  First thing you can try to do is to restart Visual Studio.  Run Visual Studio as Administrator (not required), or even restart your computer :).

Comment: Maybe you have a key pressed? Anything like shift, ctrl or alt even. Try with Console.ReadLine();

Comment: @ABuckau  - am using Visual studio 2015, you are right i was just building and not running,when I clicked on "Start" button as shown in my edit I can see the command prompt open and the output,is that the right way?thats how folks run ?

Comment: @Harry - is that the way folks run as shown in my edit?is there no buttion that will Build and run in one shot?

Comment: @user3682248 "Start" will build and run.  F5 works as well

Comment: why dont you show a screen shot of what you are seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There won't be a command window opened, the console is integrated in Visual Studio.

> Click View -> Output

to see it at the bottom.

If you want to change this behavior you can go to

> Dialog -> Debugging -> "Redirect All Output Window Text to the
>   Immediate Window"

Comment: I dont have the "Output" window but it doesnt print the  string in there,it just shows if it build successfully or failed?